# why does my dialog not close after i close an admob Advert

Tags: java, android, dialog, admob

i have a Progress dialog that shows while an app downloads. The dialog says your app is downloading please wait. with a progress bar below. it also has a button below that allows you to watch an advert.. this all works fine but if my app is downloaded before the advert is finished and i close the advert. it carries on showing the dialog at what ever percent it was on before the advert started..

i was wondering if it was possible to hide the dialog while the advert shows and bring it back when you close the advert only if the progress has not reached 100%

```
 public class h20_DownloadDialog {

public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
Context c;
Firebase mrootRef;


public h20_DownloadDialog(Context context, Firebase mrootRef) {

    this.c = context;
    this.mrootRef = mrootRef;

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.comp_ad_unit_id));
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
 onProgressUpdate();
            StartTask();

        }
    });
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}



protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
            pDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Watch Advert While you wait?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    showInterstitial();
                   Firebase advertRef = new Firebase("my Firebase ref");
                    Advert_Counter counter = new Advert_Counter(advertRef);
                    counter.count();
                }
            });

            pDialog.setTitle("H20 droid apps");
            pDialog.setMessage("Your app is downloading Please wait...");

            pDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

private void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
    if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Thanks for choosing H20.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StartTask();
    }
}

private void StartTask() {
    // Request a new ad if one isn't already loaded, hide the button, and kick off the timer.
    if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);



        }
    }



}
```

***EDIT***
ive tried this

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.getProgress();
     if (progress .equals(100)){
         pDialog.dismiss();
     }else {
         pDialog.show();
     }
}
```

***EDIT***
also tried this

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.getProgress();
     if (progress.length<= 100) {
         loadingFinished = false;
     }else{
         loadingFinished = true;
     }
     if (loadingFinished != true){
         pDialog.show();
     }else{
         pDialog.dismiss();
     }

}
```

Comment: you need change scope of pDialog to be available outside and implement onAdClosed of mInterstitial ad and check if its finished in onAdClosed https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/ad-events

Comment: thanks @ Amod Gokhale i will take a look at this now